# Open url in outlook message preview window

Tags: vba, url, outlook, window, preview

Currently I have code that will extract information from outlook message subject line and use this to open a link in IE.

I managed to break outlook the other day and these url's started opening in the outlook message preview window.

:) Does any one have any pointers on how can I code this so it happens on purpose?

I want to open the url inside the outlook application window instead of opening the url in internet explorer.

```
If subj <> "" Then
        Dim IE As Object
        With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
            If .Count > 0 Then
        ' Get IE
                Set IE = .Item(0) '.Item(.Count + 1)
            Else
        ' Create IE
                Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                IE.Visible = True
            End If
        IE.Navigate "url here"
        Set IE = Nothing
        End With
        Exit Sub
End If
```

Thanks
aj

Comment: I don't know why your question was put on hold (Andrew?), so I have to answer in the comments. The preview pane will never show an external URL - it is not even an embedded browser, it is Word. To show a url in Outlook, set the MAPIFolder WebViewOn property to true and MAPIFolder.WebViewURL to the url that you want to show.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry I edited it to make it a bit more understandable I expected it to be taken off hold by now.

Comment: Ok I have that figured out. is there a way to do this without using a specific MAPIFolder or using a temporary/hidden folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a temporary folder and make it active by setting the Applicatiobn.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder property.

Answer (score 0):

There several way to implement this task in Outlook.

1. Use the home page for the Outlook folder. The [WebViewURL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866188(v=office.15).aspx) property allows to set a string indicating the URL of the Web page that is assigned to a folder.

   Sub SetupFolderHomePage() 
       Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace
       Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder
       Dim mpfNew As Outlook.Folder
       Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
       Set mpfInbox = nsp.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
       Set mpfNew = mpfInbox.Folders.Add("MyFolderHomePage")
       mpfNew.WebViewURL = "http://www.microsoft.com"
       mpfNew.WebViewOn = True
    End Sub
2. Create an adjacent Outlook window and injkect it into the explorer window. See [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) and [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) for more information.